# How to add 2 texts in gallery under each image under the image that one will be on the right and other will be on the left in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Im trying to make the gallery to be like that

image on top
name           status
the name is easy to do I just added a caption to the image
but the status I cant figure out how to add another text

[image]

I want it to be like that to each image
I don't have a problem using external plugin as long as it's free
thanks.

Comment: A custom elementor widget can be created and a gallery can be designed according to your specifications.

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani and how do i do that?

Comment: Refer this link: **https://developers.elementor.com/docs/widgets/**

Comment: If you want then I can give you one demo example of creating a gallery with Elementor widget if you are ready to go with this approach and design it yourself.